# Get source attribute from azure graph api group object

Tags: azure, graph, azure-active-directory

Is there any way to get the 'source' field, in the response, from a graphclient getgroup()?

I need to filter groups migrated from onprem AD ('Windows Server AD') from created in AAD ('cloud'), and this seems to be the only option, as the onprem AD is long gone.

Answer (score 0):

Answer always popup after you ask..

It seems that the "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null, for groups from AAD and has a value for groups originated from on-prem ad.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).